# Php write line/strine once to code

Tags: php, html, xml, text

I am making a search function with php and I need to add `</pages>` to the end of the file I am writing too. `</pages>` can be written only once, at the end.

```
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]
["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
echo "ERR: 418 (File all ready exists)\n";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
echo "ERR: 418 (File too large)\n";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "txt") {
echo "ERR: 418 (Supported file types - .txt)\n";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"],                 
$target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). "     
has been uploaded.";
} else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}
}

$contentsbro = file_get_contents("links.xml");
$myfile = fopen("links.xml", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = "<link><title>". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). "
</title>
<url>https://fidead.000webhostapp.com/uploads/". basename( 
$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). "</url>
</link>";
$txto = $contentsbro . $txt;
fwrite($myfile, $txto);
fclose($myfile);

?>
```

I need to know how to write the string once at the end, otherwise it would give me an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you have something like this (with more entries):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<pages>
    <url>https://fidead.000webhostapp.com/uploads/filename.jpg</url>
</pages>
```

You should probably use an XML parser to do this properly:

```
# Loads the content of the file
$XML    =   simplexml_load_file('links.xml');
# Adds to the URL array
$XML->addChild('url','https://fidead.000webhostapp.com/uploads/newfile.jpg');
# Saves the file back
file_put_contents('links.xml',$XML->asXml());
```

Gives you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pages>
    <url>https://fidead.000webhostapp.com/uploads/filename.jpg</url>
<url>https://fidead.000webhostapp.com/uploads/newfile.jpg</url></pages>
```

---

EDIT:

Instead of:

```
$contentsbro = file_get_contents("links.xml");
$myfile = fopen("links.xml", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
etc....
```

You should try:

```
# Loads the content of the file
$XML    =   simplexml_load_file('links.xml');
# Make a new link child
$link   =   $XML->addChild('link');
# Create a new child under the link for title
$link->addChild('title',basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]));
# Create a new child under the link for url
$link->addChild('url','https://fidead.000webhostapp.com/uploads/'.basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]));
# Saves the file back
file_put_contents('links.xml',$XML->asXml());
```

Comment: I know very little about php so can you show me the finished code

Comment: also there is a title above the url

Comment: so it looks like this `<pages><title>name</title>
    <url>https://fidead.000webhostapp.com/uploads/filename.jpg</url>
</pages>`

Comment: The `addChild()` ignores everything else and just adds the child to the `<url>` array. You just forego the `f*()` functions in favor of the xml class/method `addChild()` and the `file_put_contents()` saves the file back.

Comment: I am still stuck. I dont know how and where to put the code

Comment: I have edited the example. Take a look at the xml parser here for the full example: http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addchild.php

Comment: Thank you. I finally got it.